# Why won't SQl MATCH AGAINST find results with only 3 characters in the result?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, match

For Example, I'm search for a person with the last name of `Ash` so in my query I search for `Ash`. It will show me people with the last name of Ashley, Ashby etc... but not people with the exact last name of Ash

Here's an example of what my sql looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `People`
WHERE MATCH(PersonFirstName, PersonLastName) AGAINST('ash*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 20
```

Is there some sort of rule that it has to be over 3 characters or something in order for MATCH AGAINST to find it?

Comment: Yes, there is some sort of rule. `ft_min_word_len`. See the answer from Barmar. Documented here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the system variable [ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len), which specifies the minimum length of words to be indexed by full-text searching. It defaults to 4, so 3-letter words won't be found by full-text searching. More information about parameters of full-text searching can be found at [12.9.6. Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html). That page explains:

> For example, if you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an option file:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

> Then restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. Note particularly the remarks regarding myisamchk in the instructions following this list.

Comment: +1. Documented here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that those were links in your above answer. The color SO uses for url's is very close to the color they use for regular text. Maybe next time you want be so snide with your remarks.

Comment: Sorry. I've complained about that myself in meta. But there's also a link in spencer's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this
SELECT * FROM `People`
WHERE MATCH(PersonFirstName, PersonLastName) AGAINST('* ash*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 20